# Unable to uninstall dbt cli and replace it with with dbt core on macos I have tried conda, brew and pip uninstall

Tags: macos, anaconda, dbt, dbt-cloud, dbt-bigquery

Output for which dbt is returning this

```
(base) aavesh@localhost ~ % which dbt
/Users/aavesh/opt/anaconda3/bin/dbt
```

then conda remove , pip uninstall and pip 3 uninstall all are failing

```
(base) aavesh@localhost ~ % conda remove dbt 
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are missing from the target environment:
  - dbt


(base) aavesh@localhost ~ % pip uninstall dbt
WARNING: Skipping dbt as it is not installed.
(base) aavesh@localhost ~ % pip3 uninstall dbt
WARNING: Skipping dbt as it is not installed.
(base) aavesh@localhost ~ % which dbt
/Users/aavesh/opt/anaconda3/bin/dbt
```

dbt init is also not working because of the error

```
(base) aavesh@localhost ~ % dbt init
Error: unknown command "init" for "dbt"
Run 'dbt --help' for usage.
```

Comment: Have you checked `conda list` to see if maybe the package just has a slightly different name? How have you installed dbt?

Comment: I can't find it and I can't remember how I installed in last year, that's why I am having trouble uninstalling. 

```
dbt-core                  1.3.1                    pypi_0    pypi
dbt-extractor             0.4.1                    pypi_0    pypi
dbt-postgres              1.3.1                    pypi_0    pypi
```
these are the 3 versions that show up when I use conda list

Answer (score 0):

Using the below 3 commands and uninstalling conda altogether fixed it for me, it was a bit of hassle but probably the best solution for someone like me who was short on time and never used conda packages anyway.

```
conda activate
conda init --reverse --all
rm -rf anaconda3
```

Answer (score 0):

The outpt from your `conda list` call:

```
dbt-core 1.3.1 pypi_0 pypi 
dbt-extractor 0.4.1 pypi_0 pypi 
dbt-postgres 1.3.1 pypi_0 pypi
```

shows that you used `pip` for the original installation, which is also what you need to use for the uninstall. Furthermore, it gives you the correct package name to uninstall:

```
pip uninstall dbt-core dbt-extractor dbt-postgres
```